# listing presentations in CV with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

Has anyone used bibtex to include a list of seminars/presentations given in a CV (kind of like a list of publications). If so, which bibtex entry do you use (`@inproceedings`, `@unpublished`...?) and which style file? I intend to use the `multibib` package to keep this section formatting separate from the list of publications, so I hope to avoid conflicts between the two sections.

Comment: I guess that `@misc` can cover this

Comment: On a sidenote, I would recommend to use Biblatex (if possible) and to use the `\fullcite` macro. I guess, the same can be achieved with `bibentry` and bibtex. This way the presentations are separate from the publications. I find `\begin{itemize} \item \fullcite{citekey1} ... \end{itemize}` appropriate for e.g. 'Your five most important publications' or such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done this and recommend

1. use the `@misc` entry type for your seminars and presentations.
2. Use `biblatex` instead of old-style bibtex in combination with `multibib`.

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.mackichan.com/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package does not only provide you built-in support for sectioned/segmented bibliographies, but also more modern styles (including full hyperref/URL/DOI support, for instance) that can more easily be customized.